Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 () - chatGPT API
I am working on angular project with node js. my method works fine locally but not working on the domain.
my website deployed on vercel.
vercel has this file vercel.json to config it before deploy
this is the method that uses chatGPT
router.post('/api/compare', async (req, res) => {
    const { v1, v2} = req.body;
    try {
        const existing = await Selected.findOne({ v1, v2});
        if (existing) {
            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'already exists.', linkId: existing.linkId });
        }

        const prompt = `long text`;

        console.log('Sending prompt to OpenAI:', prompt);

        const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
            model: "gpt-4o-mini",
            messages: [
                { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
                { role: "user", content: prompt }
            ],
            max_tokens: 1000,
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            timeout: 30000   
        });

 //////more code

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error processing');
    }
});

because chatGPT takes time to write, I get this error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()
I found some articles about adding the timing in vercel.json
but it did not work with me

{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "server.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        },
        {
            "src": "package.json",
            "use": "@vercel/static-build",
            "config": {
                "distDir": "dist/comparison/browser"
            }
        }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/api/(.*)",
            "destination": "/server.js"
        },
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/dist/comparison/browser/index.html"
        }
    ],
    "headers": [
        {
            "source": "/api/(.*)",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
                    "value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                    "value": "example.com"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                    "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
                },
                {
                    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                    "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

I have server.js in root
while routes.js in server folder
C:\Users\###\comparison\server\routes.js
C:\Users\###\comparison\server.js

I tried to run a form to compare between 2 data
I got 504 error because it took long time to run

I solved it
just in case anyone get the same issue
I found that I can maxamize the time through vercel from here
vercel functions
note: you can't add functions into vercel.json with free plan
